# Choosing application.properties using properties-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, application.properties

I have defined several application.properties files in my application. Each one is for different environments. In these files I have the data source defined for each environment.

I want to get Maven to choose the correct properties file based on the environment that the application is being deployed into. 
To do this, there is a property being passed from the WebLogic server into Spring, which is being used to determine the environment.
This property is called `weblogic.Name` I have named my application.properties files based on this WebLogic property such as:

`application-DEV.properties`

`application-UAT.properties`

In my pom.xml I have the following piece of code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.cds</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>cds-webapp-war</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>webapp-cds-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application-${weblogic.Name}.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/logback*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/*tomcat*.jar
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

However, when I try to run the application, it will fall over if I do not have a file defined with the name `application.properties`. It seems that the pom code is being ignored and it is just looking for application.properties regardless.

Thanks!

Comment: I also would recommend to use a most recent version of plugins...

Comment: I have updated to version 1.0.0 but the problem still exists

Comment: I think this could be right thing for your: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Plugins with executions have to be outside pluginManagement. Try placing your plugins outside pluginManagement.

Comment: When I remove the pluginManagement tag, I get an error on the execution tag: `properties could not be loaded from File: ...`

Comment: I resolved this error by adding ${project.version} before the filename.. but now the deployment error still exists `Failed to determine a suitable driver class`

Comment: Could you post your entire pom.xm file please?

Comment: Yes sure, I have edited the question now to include the whole pom

Comment: This error might not be due to pom.xml. Could you also include your error stack? That might help us.